# Connection to SQL Server fails on Surface but not anywhere else

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclient

I've been working on my UWP app on my development machine and everything worked fine so far. So I wanted to test it on an actual tablet using a Surface.

As soon as I deploy it via Remote Debugging it fail to connect to our internal SQL Server running on our development server. I integrated a lookup in my app which broadcasts to all SQL Server Browser instances in the network and it does find our server.

But as soon as I connect to it, I get this exception:

> "Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started."

Find the stacktrace [here](https://pastebin.com/bbZyBtYy).

The internal exception is a **SocketException**

> with the message The specified host is unknown.

relating to obviously a DNS problem. Stacktrace is [here](https://pastebin.com/GP8miRgn).

The weird thing is that this only happens on my surface. A few things I can tell you:

- The surface has SQL Server installed on, but SQL Server and the Browser service are both disabled and stopped
- The firewall is deactivated completely
- The surface is not in our domain but is configured with a static IP and the correct gateway and DNS server
- Browsing available SQL Instances in the network does work and retrieve correct results
- The SQL Server is running as named instance, the connection string is built with the `ConnectionStringBuilder` class and definetly correct (matches the one on my machine)

I'm a bit lost here. I don't get why I can contact the SQL Server Browser and yet I get an exception that it's not found. The connection string is correct, though.

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the SQL Server, using a SQL login (I assume not AD, as you said the Surface isn't in the domain). Can you see the connection attempt in the logs in the SQL Server? If not, then the connection isn't getting to the SQL Server; implying a firewall/network configuration issue. You state *"The surface has SQL Server installed on, but SQL Server and the Browser service are both disabled and stopped"*; isn't the SQL Server service running on a different host? I it isn't, and you're expecting to connect to the local instance, then why isn't the service running?

Comment: Need to see you connection string.  Have to determine if the database is using Windows Credentials or SQL credentials.  It is recommend to use windows credentials (Integrated Security=true).  Then you need a group account on the local and remote PC and have users put into group account on both machines.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But you're right, I'm using a SQL login, no AD. Thus I also disabled integrated security in the connection string. Like I said, the string is okay. It works on my machine. The local SQL server is disabled and stopped because I wanted to avoid having this as an error source. Of course it shouldn't be the problem since I am connecting to a named instance (hosted on another machine). I had to disable the browser, though because I couldn't fetch the servers due to it blocking the UDP port. Nonetheless, I see not why there's no connection possible.

Comment: I only see my login from SQL Management Studio. A connection was obviously not established at all (but that's pretty much what the exception already tells us).